# Search/Navigation in Solr (or other faceted search engines), what's the proper way?

Tags: mysql, solr, seo, faceted-search

I'm a bit confused as to where my use of Mysql should end, and where SOLR should begin.

I've got a lot of relational data (just like an ecommerce site, like amazon).

I started by putting this into mysql and ran into troubles with the size/speed, and indexing didnt help with this much data. So, I put all this data into SOLR and it's really fast. In a way, SOLR is like a cache of my MYSQL database currently (which contains multiple relational tables linked by IDs).

The thing is I'm confused about a bunch of things.

1) Is there any need for the mysql database? Can I just as easily edit and add data into the SOLR table? Is the Mysql database just adding more overhead?

2) How is it best to do the faceting and use that for search navigation? I currently unify the whole mysql database into one flat solr file. How is it best to do this when considering the many to many relationships an entry could have? Should this all be done in SOLR using the PathHierarchyTokenizer? Should I cram multiple facets into one field?

3) Is there any need to store the categories/faceets in MYSQL so that SEO titles for these pages can be created? I'm guessing this could not be done in SOLR, since there is no real concept of a page as a facet? There appears to be a need of some kind of static store/cache of facets, where additional information could be added, and it seems to make sense that this would not be done in SOLR?

4) Or should I just use SOLR as a cache for my MYSQL db? So I get all the category menus from mysql, but when a URL query happens, it gets all the products from SOLR?

Would love to hear others thoughts on this, because while solr is nice and fast, there is a big overlap with DBs and I'm struggling to get my head around where each makes sense to use.

Comment: I would post your specific questions about facetting in separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any need for the mysql database?

If you need relations between things then an RDBMS is better than Solr which has a flat, denormalized view of its world.

Solr is not generally considered as a Source of Record. If you use it as such all fields need to be "stored". Consider how you will backup and restore your data.

As a good starting point, use Solr for what it does well, search. Index just what you need to index, store what you need to store. Remember that Solr indexes can get very big with analysis and bigger indexes are less efficient.